# How to dynamically pass .Include & .Select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application , with EF-6. I am trying to dynamically pass .Include & .Select as follow:-

```
          var query = context.SecurityRoles.AsQueryable();
          foreach (var include in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
          {
              query = query.Include(include);
          }
          return await query
              .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a2 => a2.SecurityRoleID == id);
      }
```

which i will be calling as follow:-

```
var securityrole = await uniteofwork.SecurityRoleRepository
                .FindSecurityRole(id.Value, "SecurityRoleModulePermissions.Select(a2=>a2.Module),SecurityRoleModulePermissions.Select(a2=>a2.PermissionLevel)),Staffs");
```

But the i am getting the following exception:-

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'SkillManagementModel.SecurityRoleModulePermission' does not declare a
>   navigation property with the name 'Select(a2=>a2'

Comment: You can't pass code in a string like that.

Comment: @SLaks so how i can achieve this ?

Comment: `"SecurityRoleModulePermissions.Module,SecurityRoleModulePermissions.PermissionLevel,Staffs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your navigation properties dynamically like this:

```
public async Task<SecurityRole> FindSecurityRole(Expression<Func<SecurityRole, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<SecurityRole, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = context.SecurityRoles.AsQueryable();
    if (includeProperties != null)
        query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

    return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
}

var securityrole = await uniteofwork.SecurityRoleRepository.FindSecurityRole
    (sr => sr.Id == id.Value, sr => sr.Module, sr =>sr.PermissionLevel)
```